# Uniqueness of fractional parts of integer multiples of a fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

By considering lines on a torus, I had the following observation.

> Let $a/b$ be a non-zero irreducible fraction with $|a| > |b|$. Then the fractional part of the integer multiples
>   $$
> k\frac{a}{b} \qquad k \in \big\{1, 2, \ldots, (b-1)\big\}
> $$
>   are unique and are
>   $$
> \frac{1}{b},\enspace \frac{2}{b},\enspace \ldots,\enspace \frac{b-1}{b}.
> $$

It feels fairly simple to prove and is easy with explicit examples, but I can't seem to prove it in general (supposing that it *is* true in general, that is).

#### Attempt

Consider two multiples, say $ma/b$ and $na/b$ for $m \neq n$. Suppose that they have the same fractional part, say $r$. This means that there are integers $p, q$ such that
$$
ma = pb + r \qquad\text{and}\qquad na = qb + r
$$
so by rearranging we have
$$
a(m - n) = b(p - q)
$$
and
$$
\frac{a}{b} = \frac{p - q}{m - n}
$$
since $m \neq n$.

This is all that I could determine so far, and I'm not sure how to derive a contradiction from this. I would want to use the fact that $a$ and $b$ are coprime somehow (since $a/b$ is irreducible), but I couldn't figure anything else out. Hints would be more valuable than a solution for now.

Comment: You have $ma\equiv na\pmod{b}$ where $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.  Have you studied this yet?

Comment: @saulspatz Not yet, my elementary Number Theory teaching was super limited so we never got onto modular congruences with coprime numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I congratulate you.  You've rediscovered a very important fact.  The important point is that if $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, then there is a $c$ such that $ac\equiv1\pmod{b}$.  Do you see how this solves your problem?

As for how we know there is such a $c$ I suggest you read about the [extended Euclidean algorithm.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)  If the Wikipedia post is too terse, you can google "extended Euclidean algorithm" to find lots of examples.  You may want to google "Euclidean algorithm" first.

Comment: Ah yes, I remember reading that if $a$ and $b$ are coprime there are integers $c$ and $d$ such that $ac + bd = 1$. I'm struggling to use this fact though --- particularly since I cannot get a $1$ to appear with manipulations of $ma \equiv na \pmod{b}$, or anything else that would cause a contradiction.

Comment: Well, if $ac+bd=1$ then $ac\equiv1\pmod{b},$ correct?  Then multiply both sides of $na\equiv{ma}\pmod{b}$ by $c$.

Comment: Oh, and this gives that $m \equiv n \pmod{b}$! That makes a lot of sense, thank you.