# Let $p$ be prime, and $n < p$. Then $n\times i$ "hits" every residue class for $0 < i < p$. (Searching for clean proof)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Intuitively, I'm trying to show that the first $p-1$ multiples of n give every possible remainder after division by p. Or equivalently,

$$ T = \{ \; ni \mod p \; | \; i \in \mathbb{Z}, \; 1 \leq i < p\} $$

$$S = \{ a \; | \; i \in \mathbb{Z},  \; 1 \leq a < p \} $$

are equal.

Showing $T \subseteq S$ is straightforward, but my proof for $ S \subseteq T$ is two handwritten pages long and (even by my standards) convoluted.

This has the feel of well-known theorem, but I can't find it anywhere. Could someone either provide or link to a short/clean proof for the above?

Comment: This is a similar question to the one that I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2861426/uniqueness-of-fractional-parts-of-integer-multiples-of-a-fraction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that two numbers fell into the same bin: $a\cdot n\equiv b\cdot n\pmod p$. Then $(a\cdot n-b\cdot n)\equiv 0\bmod p$, so there's some number $c$ with $(a-b)\cdot n=c\cdot p$. Now, can you finish up from here? (This is where it's essential that $p$ is prime.)

Once you know that no two numbers fall into the same bin, then the rest is just an application of the pigeonhole principle: there are $p$ distinct equivalence classes of $a\cdot n\bmod p$ for $0\leq a\lt p$, and there are $p$ distinct representatives $\langle b\rangle$ of those equivalence classes with $0\leq b\lt p$, so the former must cover all the latter.

Comment: Just so I'm understanding fully: p divides c*p, so p also divides (a-b)*n. But n does not divide p (p is prime), so p divides (a-b), meaning a = b mod p. Is this correct?

Comment: Pretty close - $p$ divides $(a-b)\cdot n$, so either $p|(a-b)$ or $p|n$, and the latter is impossible since $n\lt p$.

Comment: So why is it essential that p is prime?

Comment: Because $a|b\cdot c$ doesn't necessarily imply $a|b$ or $a|c$ if $a$ isn't a prime; consider, e.g., $4|6\cdot10$.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the fact that $n$ is invertible in the ring $\mathbb{Z_p}$ so you can solve the equation

$$ni = y$$

as

$$i = n^{-1}y$$